# Windows 7 Symbolic Link - Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: windows-7, command-line, symlink

I'm trying to create a symbolic link between two directories. I have a directory called TestDocs and TestDocs2. I will be doing all my work in TestDocs, but I need it all to be reflected in TestDocs2. So all files that are in TestDocs2 will be replicated in TestDocs, and if I add a file, change a file, etc in TestDocs it should be reflected in TestDocs2.

So I thought it would be as simple as just doing this:

```
mklink /D TestDocs TestDocs2
```

But when I do that I get the error:

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Why am I getting this?

Also, do I have the order of my TestDocs and TestDocs2 wrong in the command?

Thanks for the help, Symbolic Links have always confused me!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct usage is:

```
MKLINK [options] {link} {target}
```

You're creating a link, so the `link` is the new link you're about to create.
And the `target` is the link's target, which is the existing directory.

Comment: Ok, so link can't exist already? And target would be the directory that I do all of my work in?

Comment: {link} must be non existing name. {target} must be an existing name. i.e.: {link} point to {target}.

Comment: Oh come on, czech localisation of the command help has it backwards: `MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Cíl Odkaz`

Answer (score 21):

Here is how that worked for me. 
I wanted to relocate my `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` to `F:` partition.

Steps I had to do:

1. Physically move `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache"` to `F:`. Now I had `"F:\ProgramData\Package Cache"` and `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache"` is gone since I moved it.
2. In cmd run (all in one line, split here for readability)

   ```
   mklink /J "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" 
             "F:\ProgramData\Package Cache"
   ```
3. Result:

   ```
   Junction created for C:\ProgramData\Package Cache <<===>> 
                        F:\ProgramData\Package Cache`
   ```

Comment: Why /J and not /D ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this for Google Picasa so I could access photographs on more than one machine. It works very well as Picasa is not really a netowrk enabled program.
For me I did the following:

- Install Picasa
- Run the application. This will create all the necessary database files.
- Close the application.
- Navigate to the directory where the database is - on Windows 7 it will be created in c:\users\\AppData\Local\Google
- There will be two folders Picasa2 and Picasa2Albums
  Copy these folders to a network location. In my case I created a folder called o:\PicasaDatabase and copyied these folders into it.
- Next rename the original folders to Picasa2.old and Picasa2Albums.old

Run the following commands from an elevated cmd prompt:

mklink /D "c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Picasa2" "o:\PicasaDatabase\Picasa2"

mklink /D "c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Picasa2Albums" "o:\PicasaDatabase\Picasa2Albums"

Two symbolic links will have been created in the source location and they will point to the network drive.

Obviously using symbolic links like this is a workaround for application that are not networkable and only one user can access the database at once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to make sure the Source folder does not already exist. (if it does , then rename it to something else)

In case of below Backup folder should not exist under MobileSync. Since Apple iTunes looks for Backup folder with that name, just rename the existing folder to something like OriginalBackup to avoid iTunes from finding it. Instead the mklink will synonym Backup to D: folder as below

mklink /J C:\Users\Dell\Apple\MobileSync\Backup D:\Apple\Backup\iPhoneXRBackup

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. Two things I did to fix it.

1. check I was actually in the directory I thought I was and not another one with a very similar path.
2. **put quotes around the new link name.**

First attempt:
mklink /d \shared_files ....\my-app-public\src\shared_files
gave error described.

Second attempt:
mklink /d “.\shared_files” ....\my-app-public\src\shared_files
worked fine.